# jquery hide or show groups of images

Tags: jquery, html, css

kinda stuck on this and looking for some advice.

I have a partical scirpt that when text in my menu is selected at add the class `itemSelect` then if selected again it removes the class...this is all working fine. there is also an `ALL` option that removes the class from all other menu items.

Again this is all working fine (thanks @Keith.Abramo).

The bit im stuck on is when an item is selected I need to hide and/or show images in a different list.... these images are chosen based on tags in the `data-tags` attribute.

so if if I unselect ITEM 1: `<li class=""><a href="#" rel="fe">ITEM 1</a></li>`

which has the rel `fe` all images that have `fe` in the `data-tags` attribute will hide unless of coarse that have other data-tags that are still selected (with the class `itemSelect` in the menu list).

I hope this makes sence :-S

Everything I have so far is here: http://jsfiddle.net/CmSjZ/

I have tried this myself but only messed things up and didn't know how to manage the multiple tags.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey just updated your code to make it works as you want, here is the JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CmSjZ/6/

I added these lines :

```
if ($(e).attr("class") == 'itemSelect')
            tags += $(e).find('a').attr("rel") + ' ';
```

and :

```
$('.my-images ul.images li img').hide();    
    if (tags.indexOf('All') != -1){
        $('.my-images ul.images li img').show();
    }
    else if (tags != ''){
        tags = tags.substr(0,tags.length - 1);
        var arr = tags.split(' ');
        var len = arr.length;
        for (var i = 0;i < len; i++){
            $('.my-images ul.images li[data-tags*="' + arr[i] +'"] img').show();
        }
    }
```

I'm storing the values of the tags selected in a first time.
And just after I'm parsing my tags variable to know what images we need to show without breaking your html architecture ;)

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, bind click event to all li's.
Then get rel of each li.
Get img to show according to rel.
Show it.

```
$('li').click(function(){
// Do your item select stuff here
tag = $(this).attr('rel');

$('img[data-tags="'+tag+'"]').show();
});
```

Comment: You should put some text around your answer to explain it.  I know it's straightforward but it makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/CmSjZ/9/

This should show and hide the images as per the data-tags -

```
$('.images li').hide();
$('.my-menu ul.menu li.itemSelect').each(function () {
    var rell = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
    $('.images li').filter(function (index) {
         return $.inArray(rell,$(this).attr('data-tags').split(' ')) != -1
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: indexOf("fe") would probably return true for data-tags="fem fum" as well as for "fe fu". Try splitting data-tags value and see if that array then contains the rel value ("fe").

Comment: If one would use the class attribute instead of data-tags .hasClass() could be used to look for the ~image category.